# How to find out if a method got hooked (=3rd party methods acting as a layer, used for cracking apps)

Tags: java, android, obfuscation, decompiling

There are several tools out there that can decompile an APK dex file and insert various hooks.

For example if you want to check the installer package name you need to call the function `PackageManager.getInstallerName()`.

Now as far as I am concerned they replace the reflection to the method and then either calling the real method or sending some spoofed result.

This has the huge advantage that it doesn't matter if you are calling the method natively or with a reflection.

In this particular case, `getInstallerName()` would always return `com.google.android.feedback`.

Some source code for such a hook can be found here: http://androidcracking.blogspot.de/2011/03/original-smalihook-java-source.html

Is there a way to detect these hooks?

Answer (score 0):

You could run an md5 sum against what you know to be the original apk, and a suspected pirated version of it, and compare the two.  This only guarantees that the suspected tampered version was **modified** but doesn't tell you how exactly.
The other thing you could probably do, though I have not myself tried it, but it looks promising, is something like [this](http://droiddudes.com/2011/05/08/howto-extract-apk-into-readable-java-source-code-and-xml-files/) where you would in theory be able to search for class names such as Smailhook, etc. and find out if they exist.  These ideas should at least point you in the right direction for investigating, but they may not cover all bases.

**EDIT :**  If you want to accomplish something like this at runtime (I was unaware you'd want to do this-- thought you meant a particular copy of an app that you were suspicious of, offline) you might try something like the [`Class.forName()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29) method.  Something like that or one of the other classloader methods should help search for classes within the .dex file that you are looking for, and you can catch a [`NoClassDefFoundError`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html)
to know that everything went ok.  If a class **is** found with the name you're looking for, you can handle that as you wish--terminate the program, hit a webservice that has a db of fraudulent apps behind it, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Obviously it is impossible to md5sum the APK (as soon as you store the sum, the sum changes) the only way would be to crc the classes.dex. also dex2jar would be too expensive to use at runtime. Is there a way of simply checking for classes of the smali class? Also I would need a more generic way, not just for this one tool.

Comment: Ah, did not understand that you wanted to do this at runtime :)  That changes things quite a bit.  I'll edit my response...

Comment: The `Class.forName()` is a good approach, however the class is not inserted into the DEX, but just modifies the bytecode. That means, there are no additional methods.

Comment: Right, just noticed that as well.  Let me look at it a bit more, but I'm thinking of some ideas I might try, reflection-wise, if I have time today, and I'll post my results if I am able to find anything semi-conclusive...

Comment: So I looked at some of the reflection stuff and didn't get any great ideas, but I did start thinking about the MD5 sum solution again.  I agree that it wouldn't work, if you were to re-save the new sum into the .apk file.  However, if you were to store the MD5 of the legit .apk in a database on your server, not in the .apk file where it too could be spoofed, and compare an md5 at startup of the app, that should still be a workable solution.

Comment: But then I could simply generate a CRC checksum for the DEX file, store it in a ressource and compare it at runtime. That would work indeed, but I am rather looking for a way to detect hooks. Thanks though ;)